# AH01215: Failed loading /usr/lib64/php56/modules/ioncube_loader_lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory:

Tags: php, linux, joomla3.0, ioncube, jomsocial

I constantly am seeing these error messages in my log files.

> nationalsurvivorsnetwork.co.uk [Mon Jan 30 15:17:43 2017] [error] [client 77.99.83.122:47903] AH01215: Failed loading /usr/lib64/php56/modules/ioncube_loader_lin.so:  /usr/lib64/php56/modules/ioncube_loader_lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory:

It's a Joomla installation with JomSocial professional.  Details below.

Setting Values:

```
PHP Built On                    Linux web229.extendcp.co.uk 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 26 06:52:09 UTC 2016 x86_64
Database Version                5.5.54
Database Collation              utf8_general_ci
Database Connection Collation   utf8mb4_general_ci
PHP Version                     7.0.14
Web Server                      Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
WebServer to PHP Interface      cgi-fcgi
Joomla! Version                 Joomla! 3.6.5 Stable [ Noether ] 1-December-2016 22:46 GMT
Joomla! Platform Version        Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT
```

Can someone please help me identify what's causing this error?

Comment: If you have a ubuntu , look **[at this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ioncube-loader-on-ubuntu-12-04)** to install the ioncube extension for your php installation. I can only assume that joomla is shipping with `ioncubed` code, ie encrypted/obfuscated. If your OS is otherwise, a simple google search should lead you to the appropriate instructions.

Comment: I've posted on joomla site, got a reply stating that it appears that I've installed some component that contains ioncube encrypted code.  The only components that I have installed are: JomSocial, Akeeba backup, Cometchat, Joomla quiz deluxe, various JSN components, JSPC & Kunena forum + other few bits.  A guru at Joomla has suggested asking my hosting company to enable php-ioncube-module.  As I'm on a shared host this may not be feasible,  I am wondering if installing https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php will fix the problem.  I wonder if my site has been compromised now! :-(

Comment: Hi,  I've had this response from my hosting company:

Comment: "Thank you for patience here. I have looked into your query and can confirm that PHP-ioncube-module is enabled as you can see:

Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies 
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and 
with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies 

We are unable to update this to the latest version at the moment, which might be the issue. "

Based on what hosting co have said,  Can anyone advise any further?  I've no idea of the cause

Answer (score 1):

Double check the extended file permissions in the Loader location:

```
ls -Z /usr/lib64/php/modules/
```

Change the security context of the file appropriately:

```
sudo chcon system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0 /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so
```